# Error when querying osmdata package: HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: r, openstreetmap, http-status-code-405

Recently, in R, every time I try to query the OpenStreetMap database through the `osmdata` package, I get the following error:

```
Error in `httr2::req_perform()`:
! HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed.
```

I've always used this package to download data from OpenStreetMap directly in R, but now it's not working anymore. That's an example of the code I am trying to use, which should return the bounding box of a city:

```
library(osmdata)

city_bbox <- getbb(place_name = "Milan, Italy")
```

Comment: What `packageVersion('osmdata')`, mine osmdata-0.1.10, working as expected on above query.

Comment: The version is the 0.2.3. I tried to re-install the version you are using and the error is still appearing.

Comment: With osmdata-0,2,3, still working, have you tried `debugonce(osmdata::getbb)` and stepped thru to where `httr2::req_perform()` appears?

Comment: Apparently after 1 day things started working again normally. It was probably a problem on the server side.

Comment: This HTTP 405 error was fixed in {osmdata} v0.2.4 (see https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/releases/tag/v0.2.5, https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/issues/328)

Answer (score 2):

Its curious, if I get this code specifying the boundaries of bbox as vector it works.

```
library(osmdata)
library(mapview)
library(sf)
Castalla <- opq (bbox = c (-0.88,38.49,-0.47,38.74)) %>% # 
  add_osm_feature (key = "name", value = "Castalla", value_exact = FALSE) %>%
  osmdata_sf ()
```

However trying this sample from the documentation still fails with the 405 error

```
q <- opq ("portsmouth usa") %>%
    add_osm_feature (key = "amenity", value = "!restaurant") %>%
    add_osm_feature (key = "amenity", value = "!pub") # There are a lot of these
```

Its very bizarre

Comment: Going into the exact same problem ; I have also run the code from documentation that failed;  while your code didnot

Answer (score -1):

Here's a workaround using packages `nominatimlite` and `sf`:

```
nominatim_polygon <- nominatimlite::geo_lite_sf(address = "Milan, Italy", points_only = FALSE)
bbox <- sf::st_bbox(nominatim_polygon)
```

---

It seems to be an issue within  `osmdata`'s `get_nominatim_query` function ([getbb.R](https://github.com/ropensci/osmdata/blob/main/R/getbb.R)), which can be avoided by passing a vector to `getbb()` instead of a string. This vector can be obtained by passing through `st_bbox()` an sf polygon, which we can still get with `nominalite::geo_lite_sf()` while `osmdata` is giving this 405 error.

Comment: Correct answer is to upgrade`osmdata`